# How can I autoscroll a div onmouseover and hide the scrollbar for that div?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, autoscroll

I want to autoscroll a particular  element either onmouseover or using an image map. I also want to hide the scrollbars for that div. The problem is...

I don't understand how to do this. I've been learning javascript for weeks now and I've only learned the useless parts. Nothing actually applicable to web design, that is. I did google it and nothing gave me the exact answer I was looking for, nor was I able to tweak those examples to work for me.

The code is on jsfiddle.net unless I'm breaking an unwritten rule, and please just let me know, I will just post the link. Please please please! don't just give me an answer, as I am a beginner. Please explain your solution. Thank you so much!

http://jsfiddle.net/thindjinn/KQP9t/2/

Decided to add the code, because I've gotten immediate responses before when doing that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Scrolling Pictures</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollingPictures.css" />
        <script src="/scrollingPictures.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mask"></div> <!-- White behind images, to keep color consistent when low transparency -->
        <div id="scroll">
            <img class="left" id="image1" src="http://www.yalibnan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/steve-jobs1.jpg" alt="Steve Jobs"/>

            <img class="left" id="image2" src="http://www.power-of-giving.com/image-files/achievements-of-richard-branson.jpg" alt="Richard Branson"/>

            <img class="left" id="image3" src="http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/4b16d0c70000000000134152/anderson-cooper.jpg" alt="Anderson Cooper"/>

            <img class="left" id="image3" src="http://swandiver.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/rachel-maddow.jpg?w=288&h=371" alt="Rachel Maddow"/>

            <img class="left" id="image3" src="http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2006/celebdatabase/kanyewest/kanye_west1_300_400.jpg" alt="Kanye West"/>

            <img class="left" id="image3" src="http://img1.browsebiography.com/images/gal/2627_Larry_Page_photo_1.jpg" alt="Larry Page"/>
        </div>

        <div class="gradientTop"></div>
        <div class="gradientBottom"></div>

        <div id="work"><div class="panel">Work</div></div>
        <div id="education"><div class="panel">Education</div></div>
        <div id="skills"><div class="panel">Skills</div></div>
        <div id="footer"> <a href="#home">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- Beginning of Footer -->
            <a href="#privacyStatement">Privacy Statement</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#careers">Careers</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#moreInfo">More Info</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

body{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
}
div#scroll{
    border-right:1px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
img.left{
    z-index:inherit;
    float:left;
    width:200px; 
    min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
    height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
    height:200px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
#image1, #image2, #image3{
    width:200px;
}
img.left:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
div.gradientTop{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0;
    z-index:2;
    width:206px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,2), rgba(255,255,255,0))
}
div.gradientBottom{
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    z-index:2;
    width:206px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    bottom:-210px;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1))
}
.panel{
    font-size:2em;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-top:7%;
    height:100%;
}
#work{
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    color:orange;
    position:relative; 
    text-align:right;
    max-height:500px;
    background-color:#fff; 
    min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
    min-width:700px;
    height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
    height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
}
#education{
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    color:orange;
    position:relative; 
    text-align:right;
    max-height:500px; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
    min-width:700px;
    height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
    height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
}
#skills{
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    color:orange;
    position:relative; 
    text-align:right;
    max-height:500px; 
    background-color:#ffe; 
    min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
    min-width:700px;
    height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
    height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
}
#work:hover,#education:hover,#skills:hover{
    z-index:0;
    background-color:#f0f0f9;
    border-top:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
#work:active,#education:active,#skills:active{
    z-index:0;
    background-color:#ededf2;
    border-top:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
div.mask{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    width:206px;
    height:805px;
    background-color:white;
}
#footer {
    background:white;
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-indent:5%;
    color:#333;
    clear:both;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do hide scrollbars:

Set the css property `overflow` to `hidden` on the div:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden"></div>
```

#### How to scroll the div:

The element has a scrollTop property, which is the amount of pixels the element has been scrolled. You can scroll the element by assigning to this property:

```
var div = document.getElementById(someId);
div.scrollTop = 50;
```

#### How to do something on mouseover:

```
var div = document.getElementById(someId);
div.onmouseover = function() {
    // do something here
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if changing the overflow to hidden would still allow me to autoscroll the div. That sort of worked. This only allowed me to hover over the div and have it move down 50px, no matter where on the div I hovered, it bounced back to this position. I was looking for (pseudo code):
div.onmouseover top 25%>x>20% scroll top at z speed
div.onmouseover top 20%>x>10% scroll top at z+1 speed
div.onmouseover top 10%>x>0% scroll top at z+2 speed

Same idea for bottom. I'm looking for that effect, not that specific type of syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Chech this page:
http://valums.com/vertical-scrolling-menu/

And this is the sample.
http://valums.com/files/2009/vertical-menu/final.htm

Good luck